# Java - Use polymorphism or bounded type parameters

Tags: java, polymorphism, generics

Suppose I have this class hierarchy...

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void eat();
    public abstract void talk();
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat() {
    }

    @Override
    public void talk() {
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat() {
    }

    @Override
    public void talk() {
    }
}
```

And then I have....

```
public static <T extends Animal> void addAnimal(T animal) {
    animal.eat();
    animal.talk();
}

public static void addAnimalPoly(Animal animal) {
    animal.eat();
    animal.talk();
}
```

What's the difference when using bounded type parameters or polymorphism?

And when to use one or the other?

Comment: These two definitions don't profit much from type parameters. But try writing `addAnimals(List<Animal>)` and adding a List of Cats!

Comment: Well, for example, if each of your above methods would return something aswell, then the one using generics could return T, while the other one could only return Animal. So for the person using those methods, in the first case he'd get back exactly what he wanted: Dod dog = addAnimal(new Dog()); while with the 2nd method, he'd be forced to cast in order to get a dog: Dog d = (Dog)addAnimalPoly(new Dog());

Comment: The majority of my usage of bounded types are wallpapering over Java's poor implementation of generics (List<T> has different variance rules to T alone, for example). In this case there's no advantage, it's essentially two ways of expressing the same concept, though as @ShivanDragon states it *does* mean you have a T at compiletime instead of an Animal. You can only treat it like an animal internally, but you can offer it as a T externally.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These two examples are equivalent, and in fact will compile to the same bytecode.

There are two ways that adding a bounded generic type to a method as in your first example will do anything.

**Passing the type parameter to another type**

These two method signatures end up being the same in the byte code, but the compiler enforces type safety:

`public static <T extends Animal> void addAnimals(Collection<T> animals)`

`public static void addAnimals(Collection<Animal> animals)`

In the first case, only a `Collection` (or subtype) of `Animal` is allowed. In the second case, a `Collection` (or subtype) with a generic type of `Animal` or a subtype is allowed.

For example, the following is allowed in the first method but not the second:

```
List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
cats.add(new Cat());
addAnimals(cats);
```

The reason is that the second one only allows collections of animals, while the first allows collections of any object that is assignable to animal (i.e. subtypes). Note that if this list were a list of animals that happened to contain a cat, either method would accept it: the issue is the collection's generic specification, not what it actually contains.

**Returning objects**

The other time it matters is with returning objects. Let us assume the following method existed:

```
public static <T extends Animal> T feed(T animal) {
  animal.eat();
  return animal;
}
```

You would be able to do the following with it:

```
Cat c1 = new Cat();
Cat c2 = feed(c1);
```

While this is a contrived example, there are cases where it makes sense. Without generics, the method would have to return `Animal` and you would need to add type casting to make it work (which is what the compiler adds to the byte code anyway behind the scenes).

Comment: "*In the first case, only a Collection (or subtype) of Animal is allowed. In the second case, a Collection (or subtype) with a generic type of Animal or a subtype is allowed.*" -- Do you want to double-check your logic there?

Answer (score 3):

Use generics instead of downcasting. "Downcasting" is bad, going from a more general type to a more specific one:

```
Animal a = hunter.captureOne();
Cat c = (Cat)a;  // ACK!!!!!! What if it's a Dog? ClassCastException!
```

...you're trusting that `a` is a cat, but the compiler can't guarantee that. It might turn out to be a dog at runtime.

Here's where you'd use generics:

```
public class <A> Hunter() {
    public A captureOne() { ... }
}
```

Now you can specify that you want a cat hunter:

```
Hunter<Cat> hunterC = new Hunter<Cat>();
Cat c = hunterC.captureOne();

Hunter<Dog> hunterD = new Hunter<Dog>();
Dog d = hunterD.captureOne();
```

Now the compiler can *gurantee* that hunterC will only capture cats, and hunterD will only capture dogs.

So just use regular polymorphism if you just want to handle specific classes as their base type. Upcasting is a good thing. But if you get in a situation where you need to handle specific classes as their own type, generically, use generics.

Or, really, if you find you have to downcast then use generics.

EDIT: the more general case is when you want to put off the decision of what kinds of types to handle. So the *types* become a parameter, as well as the values.

Say I want my Zoo class to handle Cats or Sponges. I don't have a common super class. But I can still use:

```
public class <T> Zoo() { ... }

Zoo<Sponge> spongeZoo = ...
Zoo<Cat> catZoo = ...
```

the degree to which you lock that down is depends on what you're trying to do ;)

Answer (score 3):

This question is old-ish, but an important factor to consider seems to have been left out regarding when to use polymorphism vs bounded type parameters. This factor may be slightly tangent to the example given in the question but, I feel, very relevant to the more general "When to use polymorphism vs bounded type parameters?"

## TL;DR

If you ever find yourself moving code from a subclass to a base class against your better judgment, because of the inability to access it in a polymorphic way, bounded type parameters could be a potential solution.

## The Full Answer

Bounded type parameters can expose concrete, non-inherited subclass methods for an inherited member variable. Polymorphism cannot

To elaborate by extending your example:

```
public abstract class AnimalOwner<T extends Animal> {
   protected T pet;
   public abstract void rewardPet();
}

// Modify the dog class
class Dog extends Animal {
   // ...
   // This method is not inherited from anywhere!
   public void scratchBelly() {
      System.out.println("Belly: Scratched");
   }
}

class DogOwner extends AnimalOwner<Dog> {
   DogOwner(Dog dog) {
     this.pet = dog;
   }

   @Override
   public void rewardPet()
   {
      // ---- Note this call ----
      pet.scratchBelly();
   }
}
```

If the abstract class AnimalOwner was defined to have a `protected Animal pet;` and opt for polymorphism, the compiler will error on the `pet.scratchBelly();` line, telling you that this method is undefined for Animal.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you don't (and shouldn't) use bounded type. *Only use bounded type parameters when you have to*, as they are more confusing to understand.

Here are some situation where you will use bounded type parameters:

- Collections parameters

  ```
  class Zoo {

    private List<Animal> animals;

    public void add(Collection<? extends Animal> newAnimals) {
      animals.addAll(newAnimals);
    }
  }
  ```

  then you can call

  ```
  List<Dog> dogs = ...
  zoo.add(dogs);
  ```

  `zoo.add(dogs)` would fail to compile without `<? extends Animal>`, because generics are not covariant.
- Subclassing

  ```
  abstract class Warrior<T extends Weapon> {

    public abstract T getWeapon();
  }
  ```

  to limit the type subclass can provide.

You can also use multiple bounds `<T extends A1 & A2 & A3>` to ensure a type is a subtype of all the types in the list.